# what does posix/Europe/Paris stand for?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

If you execute something like the following query on Postgres:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names() WHERE name LIKE '%Rome%';
```

you get back a bunch of "weird" timezones:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names() WHERE name LIKE '%Rome%';
       name        | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
-------------------+--------+------------+--------
 Europe/Rome       | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 posix/Europe/Rome | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
(2 rows)
```

I'm wondering why `posix/` exists, what they stand for (they are not IANA official timezones right?) and when they are used. They look like a blend of POSIX standard and Olson DB, but posix should have -1 as utc_offset, right? I'm considering using the `pg_timezone_names()` function for giving the users the chance of choosing their own timezone, but I can't understand the meaning of this specific type of timezone in Postgres.

Comment: it seems to be `CET` timezones

Comment: you can change time zone by session or on postgres conf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone

Comment: it's `CET` indeed as the abbrev column says, but I want the users to save their timezone preferences. For that reason I want to give them a list of available timezones. But those ones that look like "posix/Europe/Rome" do not make much sense to me! So, I'm wondering why they place those timezone items in postgres and what are their real meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't be using the `Posix/` or `Etc/` timezones if they're on your system. This isn't a PostgreSQL thing, it's your distributions libc database (sometimes packaged as tzdata/zoneinfo) for the internal [timezone functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Zone-Functions.html). Most of that POSIX stuff is nasty and old. PostgreSQL has a [document on it which mentions it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

I guess to [answer the question specifically,](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2011-June/008587.html)

> Two different versions are provided: - The "posix" version is based on the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). - The "right" version is based on the International Atomic Time (TAI), and it includes the leap seconds.

There really is no reason that I know of *not* to use the IANA names.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Evan Carroll answer, you can get a list by using something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names()
WHERE name LIKE 'Europe%' 
      AND abbrev = 'CET'
ORDER BY name
;
```

The result is:

```
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
|        name       | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Amsterdam  | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Andorra    | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Belgrade   | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Berlin     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Bratislava | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Brussels   | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Budapest   | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Busingen   | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Copenhagen | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Gibraltar  | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Ljubljana  | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Luxembourg | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Madrid     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Malta      | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Monaco     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Oslo       | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Paris      | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Podgorica  | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Prague     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Rome       | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/San_Marino | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Sarajevo   | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Skopje     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Stockholm  | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Tirane     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Vaduz      | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Vatican    | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Vienna     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Warsaw     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Zagreb     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Europe/Zurich     | CET    | 01:00:00   | False  |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
```